# Google sheet 'function returned undefined, expected promise or value'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a function that appends a row every time I add a record in my firestore database. I am doing it through a service account. Here is my code.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const { promisify } = require('util');
exports.loadInformation = functions.firestore.document('incident-report/{id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  console.log('Im triggered')
  exports.main = (req, res) => {
    google.auth.getClient({
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
    }).then(auth => {
      const api = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth });
      const getSheets = promisify(api.spreadsheets.get.bind(api.spreadsheets));
      return getSheets({ spreadsheetId: '1hCF8jDt6uqYZ7qC93To2n0MbGzDWPIBU72IMp2xqh5Y' });
    })
      // This just prints out all Worksheet names as an example
      .then(({ data: { sheets } }) => {
        res.status(200).send({ sheets });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({ err });
      })
    }
});
```

But I get this error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value.

Please check. Can anybody give me a solution please?

Comment: What line causes that error?

Comment: Assigning `exports.main` inside a callback doesn't really make any sense.  All exports must be defined at the top level of the module.